# @Version not incremented

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Here is my simple entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Version;
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    @Version
    @Column(name="version")
    private Long version;

    @Version
    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    @Version
    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

I added @Column and @Version to getter and setter because it is not working. The version in the mysql database was initially null and then 0. When I do a

```
order = em.merge(order);
```

the version is NOT incremented. Why? I hoped that the version is incremented automatically during merge and to get an javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException when the version does not match. Do I need something like @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)?

Also, what is org.springframework.data.annotation.Version? Should I use that? What does it do?

I am using spring boot 1.5.3.

Comment: `@Version` on field should be enough. Normally the version gets updated, but there must be a change in the entity for the merge to update the version. So be sure that `order` has changes.

Comment: Of course, my changes are only in sub-entities ....

Comment: ok, then your sub-entities should be updated if you have the @Version annotation set in those. Is it working if you really change something in your order entity?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you very much for your quick help. You nailed it

Comment: perfect. Just provided an answer for people who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to have the `@Version` annotation on the field. You should also be sure that the `entity` has really changes. Because if the `entity` has no changes there will be no update on the version. Also `Sub-Entities` just get updated if there is `@Version`explicity set.

In your case `order` should have a change to get the version updated. (Not the sub-entities)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old question, but still pops up as a first thread in Google search. I had similar issue, however with totally different root cause.

I used @Version annotation from package:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Version;
```

where it should have been:

```
import javax.persistence.Version;
```

Maybe someone finds this usefull.

Comment: upvote this man